# Datagrid View in a custom control

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, custom-controls

I am trying to add datagridview control in my custom control but i failed.

I started creating new project[windows custom control library], added datagridview control on it and also added a property naming "DGVMain" which refers to datagridview control.

I compiled it.

While testing i find its properties like visible and other working but when i click on columns property it doesn't work. i.e i cannot add/edit columns into the datagridview of my custom control.

Did i miss any steps or do i need to add some more actions?

Comment: Is there any other user control beside the Datagrid?

Comment: nope... none others are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't have other control within your custom control, maybe an inherited user control would be more appropriate in this case and I'm sure it will also fix your problem.